# Display connection specific cookies in Erlang

Tags: erlang

When setting a cookie on a node with `erlang:set_cookie/2` it is possible to set different cookies for different nodes. Is there any way to display, which cookie is set for which node?

Calling `erlang:get_cookie/1` does not display this information, only the "default" cookie is displayed.

Example:

Start NodeA with cookie `foo` and a NodeB with cookie `bar`. At NodeA now set the cookie to use when communicating with NodeB to `bar` by calling `erlang:set_cookie(NodeB, bar)`. Pinging now works fine, no "Connection attempt from disallowed node..." errors. Calling `erlang:get_cookie()` on NodeA however still shows the "default" cookie `foo`. How can find which cookie is set for NodeB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be documented, but `auth:get_cookie/1` does what you want. For your case, you can call `auth:get_cookie(NodeB)` on `NodeA`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `get_cookie/0` function on NodeB to get the name for that node. Simple solution is to do (on NodeA):

```
rpc:call(NodeB, erlang, get_cookie, []).
```

after you have connected the nodes.

Doing the `erlang:set_cookie(NodeB, bar)` call on NodeA just makes it possible for NodeA/NodeB to connect to each other, they still have their original cookies.

But to be able to connect to the other node you must already know the cookie for that node :)